# Will Dapper not work with members that have custom getters/setters?

Tags: .net, dapper

Based on some code I am working with this appears to be the case.  I couldn't find anything in the [dapper documentation](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) that explicitly said that it won't work with members that have custom get/set logic, but I did see this example:

```
public class Dog
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float? Weight { get; set; }

    public int IgnoredProperty { get { return 1; } }  //red flag?
}
```

It seems like the fact that the one member that has custom get behavior is prefixed with `Ignored` might suggest that Dapper will not try to populate these values.  Is this true?  Is this in the documentation and I just overlooked it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason dapper will ignore that one is that *it doesn't have a setter*. It doesn't care how your properties are implemented internally, but it *needs* a setter to use a property (although the setter doesn't have to be public).

It can also use fields, as an aside.

Comment: can you point to docs on using non-public setters? I would like to encapsulate the setter via code, but still use Dapper to set it from the DB.  Can I have a private or protected setter?

Comment: @Thiago yes; just add the keyword `private`, `protected` or `internal` before the `set`

Comment: thanks!  I get the private setter syntax, just wasn't sure if there was anything we had to do with dapper in order for it to access and set those properties if they're marked with private setters, like we have to do with NHibernate or some other big ORM framework.

Comment: @Thiago I'm a great believer that "it should just work" is a good default