# Dapper not recovering properties from base class

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a fairly simple hierarchy:

```
public class BaseClass
{
     public int Id { get; }
}

public class Inherited : BaseClass
{
     public double Value { get; }
}
```

When I do Query(command), the Value properties get the right values, but all the Id's are zero.

Comment: Have you tried using `init` properties instead of read-only properties, eg `public int Id { get; init; }`? Right now you depend on quirky behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will Dapper not work with members that have custom getters/setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289168/will-dapper-not-work-with-members-that-have-custom-getters-setters)

Comment: EIther use a setter, or use a constructor

Answer (score -1):

(This took me a while).

On the base class, you need the setter on the property, whereas on the inherited class, Dapper seems to be able to manage without.

---

As Panagiotis says, adding an 'init' is a good compromise.

Comment: I didn't think that Dapper would inject its own constructor into your classes. Neither of your properties have setters, so the only way to set the properties is through a constructor.

Comment: This happens because Dapper goes through some weird implementation-dependent tricks to find the name of the backing field and set it. That was a necessity before C# 9 and init-only setters.

Comment: Have you tried using `init` properties instead of read-only properties?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks, didn't even know they existed, trying now.